# How often are signals aimed at receivers?

Tags: wireless

This is a total newbie question. When phones, radios, computers, satellites, and the like transmit signals, how often are they "aimed" at the receiver (a satellite, radio tower, etc), as opposed to transmitting information in every direction?

I have not read any books about this, but a fairly thorough Google search oddly did not result in any articles that were particularly relevant. I don't know of any aiming device on phones and radios, so making them aim seems unlikely. However, phones and GPS can receive signals from very far away, which seems hard for unarmed signals to achieve.

Comment: Short answer, yes the mobile can't know where the tower is, but GPS is different thing, the mobile don't send any data just received signals from 2-3 satellites and calculate the location

Comment: Rarely. (ie. cases of point-to-point RF links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to clarify that no antenna transmits in "every direction" as you put it. Such an antenna is called an [isotropic antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_radiator) and is purely a hypothetical construct used to provide a comparison in measuring/comparing radio transmit power. Actual physical antennas will always have directions/areas where they provide little to no signal.

What you are most likely referencing is the class of antenna that are known as [omnidirectional antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnidirectional_antenna). These will typically provide 360 degrees of coverage on the horizontal plane (or azimuth) and significantly less on the vertical plane (or elevation). If interested, you can learn more about understanding antenna patterns from this [Cisco document](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-antennas-accessories/prod_white_paper0900aecd806a1a3e.html) or [Cisco's Aironet Antenna Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-antennas-accessories/product_data_sheet09186a008008883b.html).

Second, when you "aim" a radio signal, it isn't like aiming something like a laser. RF never follows a straight line from point A to point B. Even the most directional antennas will radiate signal out covering a pattern that will be measured in degrees and will have "lobes" that provide weaker signals to the sides or rear of the main lobe.

Third, I want to highlight that many wireless devices use bidirectional communication and are both a transmitter and a receiver (i.e. transceiver). So your examples of receivers (satellite, radio tower, etc) are also typically transmitters as well. This carries over to making your cell phone and any 802.11 wireless devices both transmitters and receivers.

Now, back to the heart of your question:

> how often are they "aimed" at the receiver

In some sense, fairly often. Most cellular towers consist of a number of separate transceiver (transmitter/receiver) arrays designed to provide a combined 360 degrees of coverage. 802.11 wireless access points are often positioned or utilize antennas to provide coverage primarily in certain directions.

However, you seem to be looking more for even more "targetted" transmissions such as point-to-point installations. These are considerably rarer when compared to other types of installations for two reasons.

Primarily because when using highly directional antennas, there is little room for either end point to change location, so both typically have to be in fixed locations (even some directional wireless with end points on skyscrapers can have degraded performance on windy days).

Secondarily, because they are in fixed locations and transmitting in a fixed direction, they can only do so to sites in that specific direction. Any site that is not in that direction will receive little to no coverage making a point-to-multipoint installations of this type even rarer.

In contrast, point-to-multipoint installations with omnidirectional antennas (or an array of transceivers covering 360 degrees) allows coverage to devices that are mobile and in any general direction around the installation point.

Comment: With multiple antennas and beamforming you can also achieve an "aimed" behavior without the need for directional antennas.

Answer (score 2):

Phones and computers use omnidirectional (or more-or-less omnidirectional) antennas. Access points and especially cellular sites my use directional antennas, though most access points are omnidirectional as well.

Satellites (at least modern ones, as compared to Sputnik, or good old [Echo-1](http://www.nasa.gov/missions/science/f-satellites.html) which was just a radio-reflecting balloon in orbit) will, if covering the whole earth, use an antenna that covers the earth, not all of space. And they may use an array of multiple antennas covering smaller portions of the earth, depending what services they are offering.

Point to point wireless links are nearly always directional antennas, since the direction to the other antenna is known and fixed.